# ng-repeat with hashmap doesn't display anything on my html table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to display a table with hashmap values.

my js hashmap is following:

```
self.userList["user1"] = {sms:true,email:false}
self.userList["user2"] = {sms:false,email:false}
self.userList["user3"] = {sms:true,email:true}
self.userList["user4"] = {sms:false,email:false}
```

and my view is following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(user,value) in editRulesCtrl.userList">
                                <td>
                                     {{user}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  <md-checkbox ng-model="{{value.sms}}"></md-checkbox>
                                </td>
                                <td >
                                   <md-checkbox ng-model="{{value.email}}"></md-checkbox>
                                </td>
</tr>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong, but table shows up empty.

Comment: in ng-repeat, I don't think you need editRulesCtrl,  just userList

Comment: just tried it, but still did not work.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, only problem I can see is, `ng-model` needs variable `name`, it does failed if you try to pass `{{}}`(interpolation) to it.

```
<tr ng-repeat="(user,value) in editRulesCtrl.userList">
    <td>
      {{user}}
    </td>
    <td>
      <md-checkbox ng-model="value.sms"></md-checkbox>
    </td>
    <td>
      <md-checkbox ng-model="value.email"></md-checkbox>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/foKdEoCnl7J5fJvam7mr?p=preview)

Comment: @MustafaBereket Makk answer as checked, if it helped, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat="(user,value) in userList">
```